# How to use a test in another test in Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a test of Login, I want to use the same step in other tests as well. I am willing to know if it can be done simply by calling that step or I need to write all the steps in all tests.
Please help!!

Comment: My Login Steps is:

module.exports = {
  'Login to XYZ' : function (XYZ) {
    XYZ
      .url('http://192.0.0.0/Login.aspx')
      .waitForElementVisible('input[name="Login1$UserName"]', 8000)
      .setValue('input[name="Login1$UserName"]', 'gourav@xyz.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('input[name="Login1$Password"]', 8000)
      .setValue('input[name="Login1$Password"]', '1234')
      .click('input[id="Login1_LoginButton"]')
},
}

Now I want to use this Login Step as a common for any test.

Comment: You should look at using page objects. That is a better solution for what you are trying to do. http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#page-objects